# how to check if text exists in javascript var

Tags: javascript

I have a var that contains some text. I would like to check whether the texts has a certain word.

Example:

```
var myString = 'This is some random text';
```

I would like to check if the word "random" exists. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to test for the word "random" specifically, you can use a regular expression like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JMjpY/

```
var myString = 'This is some random text';
var word = 'random';
var regex = new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b' );

var result = regex.test( myString );
```

This way it won't match where "random" is part of a word like "randomize".

---

And of course prototype it onto String if you wish:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JMjpY/1/

```
String.prototype.containsWord = function( word ) {
    var regex = new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b' );
    return regex.test( this );
};

myString.containsWord( "random" );
```

Comment: I've been using this, but it doesnt seem to work with some characters, eg: -5 degrees (returns false with the minus)

Any ideas to fix?

Comment: @Ricky: You could do `new RegExp( '\\s|\\b' + word + '\\s|\\b' );`, but then if the string contains `-5 degrees`, it would give a positive result if searching for `5 degrees`.

Comment: It seems to always return true now.

Comment: @Ricky: I forgot to group them. `new RegExp( '(\\s|\\b)' + word + '(\\s|\\b)' )`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a standalone function:

```
function contains(str, text) {
   return str.indexOf(text) >= 0);
}

if(contains(myString, 'random')) {
   //myString contains "random"
}
```

Or with a prototype extension:

```
String.prototype.contains = String.prototype.contains || function(str) {
   return this.indexOf(str) >= 0;
}

if(myString.contains('random')) {
   //myString contains "random"
}
```

Comment: If the searched word is the first of the text it will be ignored with your `>= 0`. _indexOf_ return _-1_ if nothing found.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to Jacob,
There is a missing Opening Bracket in the 'contains' function.

> ```
> return str.indexOf(text) >= 0);
> ```

should be

```
return (str.indexOf(text) >= 0);
```

---

**I have opted for Patricks Answer and adapted it into a function**

### Example

```
function InString(myString,word)
    {
    var regex = new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b' );
    var result = regex.test( myString );
    return( result );
    }
```

Call the Function with

```
var ManyWords='This is a list of words';
var OneWord='word';
if (InString(ManyWords,OneWord)){alert(OneWord+' Already exists!');return;}
```

This would return False because although 'words' exists in the variable ManyWords, this function shows only an **exact** match for 'word'.